# "File type RAR archive (application/x-rar) is not supported"

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, xubuntu, 16.10, archive

I'm trying to open these comic (CBR) files using `comix`, `mcomix`, and `evince`.

[image]

```
file Venom*
Venom 163 (2018) (Digital) (Zone-Empire).cbr:              RAR archive data, v1d, os: Win32
Venom - First Host 001 (2018) (Digital) (Zone-Empire).cbr: RAR archive data, v1d, os: Win32
```

Is it not possible to open these file types using ubuntu?

Comment: On Lubuntu 16.04 I have Evince 3.18.2. I already had libunrar. After installing unrar Evince opened CBR.